# How to add time and time intervals in SQL queries

Tags: postgresql

I want to check the late comers and early goers for a particular attendance table. My attendance table looks like this:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ date_record ║ checkinTime ║ Emp_code ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2019-02-01  ║ 09:00:00    ║ p-01     ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2019-02-01  ║ 09:30:00    ║ p-02     ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2019-02-01  ║ 10:00:00    ║ p-03     ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2019-02-01  ║ 09:30:00    ║ p-04     ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

suppose the actual time is `09:00:00` and i want to show the employee code (`Emp_code`) who got late by 30 minutes. if i want to check the above like this:

```
select Emp_code from attendanceTable where checkinTime = ('09:00:00' + '00:30:00');
```

How can i do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming `checkintime` is properly declared as a `time` column, just add [an interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

```
select *
from attendancetable 
where checkintime = time '09:00:00' + interval '30 minutes';
```

But you probably want to use `>=` instead of `=` to also include employees that arrived e.g. 34 minutes late.

Comment: can we use the actual time instead of using `minutes` after interval like this: `00:30:00`?

Comment: @RameshRaghavan: what do you mean with "actual time"? Do you mean `current_time + interval '30 minutes`?

Comment: i have sorted it out, i used the query like this, `select * from attendancetable where checkintime = time '09:00:00' + interval '00:30:00';`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose better query would be :

select * from attendancetable WHERE checkintime>=DATE_TRUNC('DAY',checkintime)+interval '9 hours' +interval '30 minutes'

So by using this you can get expected result for all dates.